# Installing ghc-mod on Windows

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, cygwin, haskell

I am trying to set up Atom as my Haskell IDE. I have already installed Haskell, and all of the Haskell plugins I need in Atom. I ran `cabal install ghc-mod`, which failed to install/configure `old-time`, which requires Cygwin. So I downloaded Cygwin (64-bit). After thirty minutes of realizing that I had to reboot my computer to update the PATH variable (which shouldn't be the case) I was able to use `sh` from the command line, but not `old-time` complained that the C compiler wasn't able to create executables. Using the 32-bit version didn't help. I don't even know what to do any more. Is there any way I can get `ghc-mod` to work without `old-time`? If not, what do I need to do from here? [Here is the error I get with `cabal update && cabal install ghc-mod`](http://paste.ee/p/QknDb). I am using Windows 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this error by doing the install through MINGY64, I'm using Windows 10 64bit as well. This is the preferred command-line installed during install of GitHub on Windows so I had it already setup. Right clicking the desktop shows "Git Bash Here".

However, there are install directions here: [these are the MinTTY install directions](http://rperki.blogspot.com/2015/05/installing-mingw-w64-msys-on-win-81-x64.html). `cabal update && cabal install ghc-mod` should do the trick from here. Before this solution I had tried from Powershell as well as Cygwin64 and had no success. MinTTY worked like a charm.